# how can i develop application for all android devices ? what setting can i put on simulator that work on most devices?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

What simulator resolution i should keep when developing application for Samsung galaxy s2 and galaxy s3 ?

What i found that samsung galaxy s2 has 480x800 resolution and s3 has 1280x720 resolution so what i have understood up till now that I should ask my graphics designer to provide me hdpi graphics that contain 480x800 background images and to implement same background image in galaxy s3 mobile, I will use image of size 1280x720 and put in xhdpi folder so that it can work on s3.

The background image is something which covers whole available area for mobile app. so am i right ??

Comment: the screen resolution is your last problem. Note that there are different versions of android - the last SDK is number 15. If you want your application to run on most devices you should develop it for SDK 8. In later updates some methods become obsolete. In Honeycomb the sqlite cursors are handled in very different way than in Gingerbread for example. It's quite impossible to guarantee that the app will work everywhere. About the resolutions - check the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create several emulators or get various devices.

There are some pretty important ones, so generally you need to make sure you have:

```
ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi
```

and

> small, medium, large, xlarge

Some people choose to exclude certain sizes (like small and ldpi) but htat's up to you,

if you go with some or all of the following, it should be a good start:

> ```
> 480x320 (SE Mini 10), 480x800 (GS2, Desire, etc), 1280x720 (GS3, Galaxy Nexus etc), 1280x800 (Note, Xoom, various other tablets)
>
> HTC ChaCha (because it's landscape default)
> ```

You need to make sure you create resources in the relevant folders for each density, usually, I tend to ignore ldpi and just put resources in:

> mdpi,hdpi and xhdpi (mdpi will be scaled down for ldpi devices,
>   automatically)

You may also need to create various portrait and landscape layouts in different sizes.

Reading this page provides most of the necessary information:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

This page also contains important information regarding size distribution and popularity that is constantly up to date:

[Android Stats](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

One thing that Android does for you is that it manages resolution. If you use the proper size formats (`dp`, `sp`, etc), your layout will scale to almost all resolutions. If you place images in the proper drawable folders (hdpi, ldpi, mdpi, etc), the OS will also swap those out as necessary.

Also, the emulator should handle resolutions for specific devices, if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Desing lazout in smart way! Usualy it means don't put to mutch content in one layout.
Make sure that evrything looks good on smallest size and bigest size. It is better to treat tablets separetly. Read how [providing alternative resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) works, you can build sepereate layouts for each screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the hardware is available on that device before using it. hasSystemFeature() can be used for checking.